# AnythingSlider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

I've recently implemented anythingslider into my website (built on wordpress). The default slider works great.

I was reading into the docs on github and want to use it exactly like this demo. http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/76/.

This is the perfect functionality for my site. However, when I copy the code over from jsfiddle to my site it doesn't work at all. Even though i already have the slider working on the page with this code:

```
// DOM Ready
$(function(){
 $('#sliderwho').anythingSlider({
  buildArrows         : false,
  buildStartStop      : false,
  autoPlay            : true, 
  mode                : "fade",
  appendControlsTo    : '.slider-nav',
  hashTags            : false,
 });
});
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

with `hashTags            : false,` you have a trailing "," which tells JS that there is supposed to be another property for your object.

with the limited code you provided thats all i saw - I'm making the assumption you have event handlers elsewhere....

so an updated version of the object would look like

```
// DOM Ready
$(function(){
 $('#sliderwho').anythingSlider({
  buildArrows         : false,
  buildStartStop      : false,
  autoPlay            : true, 
  mode                : "fade",
  appendControlsTo    : '.slider-nav',
  hashTags            : false  /*removed the extra ','  */
 });
});
```

Comment: I removed this code to put the one i took from jsfiddle. The one above works perfect. But the one that i want http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/76/ doesnt. Could it be something to do with the way its loaded in my site? I just have it between two <script> tags in the footer

Comment: just calling the cards as i see them. "asking me to guess at something else that might be an issue that isn't disclosed" isn't conducive to either of our health. If you are still having issue with this, post the source in its entirety (*names and faces can be changed to protect the innocent - DRAGNET ) and id be happy to give you further insight. :)